# Why is my custom parameter converter class not used?

Tags: 8, routes

I start banging my head on the table, the wall or anything else... please help me.

Here is my my_module.routing.yml:

```
my_module.api.validate_coupon:
  path: '/api/v1/{coupon_code}/validate'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\API\ValidateCouponController::validate'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      coupon_code:
        type: coupon_code_converter
```

This is my services.yml

```
services:
  paramconverter.coupon_code_converter:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\CouponCodeConverter
    tags:
      - { name: paramconverter }
```

This is my converter class - it is taken from Drupal\language\LanguageConverter and I added some breakpoints which should make the script stop in my IDE:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;
use Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

/**
 * Converts a coupon code to a fully loaded coupon
 */
class CouponCodeConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function convert($value, $definition, $name, array $defaults) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
      return $this->languageManager->getLanguage($value);
    }
    return NULL;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies($definition, $name, Route $route) {
    return (!empty($definition['type']) && $definition['type'] == 'language');
  }
}
```

And this is my controller class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\API;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class ValidateCouponController extends ControllerBase  {

  public function validate($coupon_code) {
    $container = \Drupal::getContainer();
    $kernel = $container->get('kernel');
    $services = $kernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()['services'];
    ksort($services);
    return array(
      '#markup' => 'hallo'
    );
  }
}
```

I can enter http://mypath.com/api/v1/1/validate and the controller gets the value '1' for $coupon_code. But I want my CouponCodeConverter class to do some magic before the parameter gets sent to the Controller... but the converter gets not called... what do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the condition in applies() doesn't match with the route parameters, try this:

```
  public function applies($definition, $name, Route $route) {
    return (!empty($definition['type']) && $definition['type'] == 'coupon_code_converter');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I placed a Breakpoint in the applies() method but the script does not stop there. Thank you

Comment: When do you expect this to happen? This is part of the route building process and usually doesn't run in a normal request.

Comment: Ah ok.. I though like the AccessController on every request this applies() function would be called. Thank you for that clarification.